# Is it possible to download a file to the directory folder and then import it?

Tags: react-native, filesystems

I have a problem and I can't solve it! My App in React-Native has a bunch of screens. One screen uses a JSON file that right now is inside a the App Project Folder:

```
import test from "../test.json"
```

I want to replace this because obviously if I want to change the JSON I need to change the file inside the App Project Folder. So I wanted to download the file and then import it the same way. I successfully downloaded the file in a temporary directory but I could not import it because it was not inside the App Project Folder.
I'm using a React-Native library called react-native-blob-util. One function of the library (ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs) tells me all the directories:

```
{"ApplicationSupportDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Library/Application Support", "CacheDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Library/Caches", "DCIMDir": undefined, "DocumentDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Documents", "DownloadDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Downloads", "LibraryDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Library", "MainBundleDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C6148120-2378-44B7-BE2A-B4FFBDE6668D/TypeTest.app", "MovieDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Movies", "MusicDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Music", "PictureDir": "/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CDC9FD4-9CA6-4FDC-BBBA-12A17D7523C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/CF3BF7FD-CE84-439E-9BB9-EF318D685F81/Pictures", "SDCardApplicationDir": undefined, "SDCardDir": undefined}
```

Is it possible to download the JSON inside the project folder or some other directory when the user logs and then import the file in another screen?

Comment: It is possible. You might need additional permissions to read/ write storage on android. Maybe [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) might be useful for you.
If it is not a very long JSON file you could even directly convert the API response to object instead of saving it to disk

Comment: @sushrut619 I need to save it to disk for offline use. But what is the directory to save it and the import it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not `import` a file that you downloaded to the device storage in runtime. You need to read it from the file system to use that file.

But depending on your setup there are easier ways to do what you want to accomplish.
I'd recommend you save your json file content to your application state  (like `redux` or any other state management solution) and update your state after fetching the new json. If you want to persist the updated state between launches, you can use `redux-persist` so you wouldn't have to worry about the content being up to date.